# how can I upgrade wsp with compatibility mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have an wsp in Sharepoint2007 ,and I need to used in SharePoint2010.
How can I upgrade the solution.
beast regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

already answered here:

> It will depend on many things such as "are these 3rd party products?"
>   - try to find newest versions (if exists and license allows you to), otherwise try to just re-install them on 2010. You need also to ask
>   whether you plan to add/update more functionality? - if yes and you
>   have the option, then you should probably invest in actual migrating
>   the code to benefit from the new .NET 3.5 features, new improved API,
>   etc.
>
> Many tools existed at the time (WSPBuilder being most used to create
>   .WSP packages), StSDev or even Visual Studio Extensions for WSS by
>   Microsoft, make sure you choose an appropriate path to migrate. Visual
>   Studio 2010 replaces the need for any of those tools now (e.g. support
>   automatic import from a solution based on VSE for WSS).
>
> You need to assess a little, we only highlight options and
>   recommendations.

[how to migrate web parts with .wsp solution package from sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36386/how-to-migrate-web-parts-with-wsp-solution-package-from-sharepoint-2007-to-shar)

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549684/migrating-moving-upgrading-a-sharepoint-2007-project-and-deploying-it-to-sharepo